Resolving C2676 Error in Template Class PriorityEntry: Overloaded Operator< Fix
I have the class
template<typename T>
class PriorityEntry {
    public:
        PriorityEntry();
        PriorityEntry(const int& priority, const T& data);

        int getPriority() const;

        bool operator<(const T& rhs);

    private:
        int priority;

        T data;
};

and a seperate class LinkedSortedList that is wrapped in a PriorityQueue with the following public method
template<typename T>
bool LinkedSortedList<T>::insertSorted(const T& entry) {
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(entry);
    Node<T>* prev    = nullptr;
    Node<T>* curr    = head;
    while (curr != nullptr && curr->getData() < entry) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->getNext();
    }
    if (prev == nullptr) {
        newNode->setNext(head);
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        newNode->setNext(prev->getNext());
        prev->setNext(newNode);
    }
    count++;
    return true;
}

along with the main program
int main() {
    LinkedPriorityQueue<PriorityEntry<string>> priorityQueue;

    PriorityEntry<string> entryOne(3, "Name One");
    priorityQueue.enqueue(entryOne);

    PriorityEntry<string> entryTwo(9, "Name Two");
    priorityQueue.enqueue(entryTwo);

    PriorityEntry<string> entryThree(2, "Name Three");
    priorityQueue.enqueue(entryThree);

    PriorityEntry<string> entryFour(1, "Name Four");
    priorityQueue.enqueue(entryFour);
    
    return 0;
}

and the constructors are
template<typename T>
LinkedPriorityQueue<T>::LinkedPriorityQueue() {
    list = new LinkedSortedList<T>();
}

template<typename T>
LinkedSortedList<T>::LinkedSortedList() {
    count = 0;
    head  = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
PriorityEntry<T>::PriorityEntry() {
    priority = 0;
    data     = T();
}

My problem is that the overloaded operator< is not working. I get a C2676 error saying no operator found which takes a right - hand operand of type 'const T' (or there is no acceptable conversion). Any idea how I can go about fixing this? I tried adjusting the parameters of operator< to no avail. Any help is appreciated.
The operator< is defined as
template<typename T>
bool PriorityEntry<T>::operator<(const T& rhs) {
    return this->priority < rhs.getPriority();
}


We need a [mcve]

did you actually define operator < ? you only showed us the header declatartion

@user12002570 I will post one when I get home

Also, you operator only allows comparing non-const PriorityQueue<T> and const T, in this order. I'm not sure if that's the expected behaviour.

@Yksisarvinen I’ll have to update this question later. I want to make the comparison curr->getData() < entry on the fourth line of insertSorted() knowing that the left hand side would be a PriorityEntry<string> and the right hand side would be a const T& entry. I thought those operands matched the parameters I defined for the operator.

Your operator cannot act on an rvalue used as left operand and isn't considered.
template<typename T>
bool PriorityEntry<T>::operator<(const T& rhs) const {
    return this->priority < rhs.getPriority();
}

P.S. expression this->priority < rhs.getPriority(); is weird - it breaks open-closed relationship with implementation of T, but not completely. If you're in same class, you can write this->priority < rhs.priority. But in template, where T is whatever, you can separate it from implementation and this->getPriority() < rhs.getPriority()

Unfortunately this didn't work. I ended up replacing curr != nullptr && curr->getData() < entry with curr->getData().getPriority() < entry.getPriority(). The program runs as expected but I don't like how this condition looks, and would like to change it. Also, I'm unsure what you mean by open-closed relationship with implementation.

@xvynp your problem is in code you never had shown, not in code you provided. Your overloaded operator compares PriorityEntry<T> with T  which is atypical . It means that you cannot compare two PriorityEntry, instead you compare  PriorityEntry<T>  implementation detail with something obtained from T via public interface, which looks as if T actually got access to priority. SO why there is separate priority in PriorityEntry?

Very stupid mistake on my part. I misunderstood how my code was running. I redefined the operator< to take const PriorityEntry<T>& rhs as an argument, which solved the problem.
